# How to insert date from multiple selects to another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, magento

I need to fill a table, ABC, with the data from MDB table after some transformations, means each row in MDB will create an entry in ABC table. I wrote a Mysql Query in Format -

```
Insert into ABC (a,b,c) select some_operation(d, <ext_value>) as a, e as b, f as c;
```

This sql query will insert a copy/modified copy of MDB data to ABC. What I next i Need is to change the ext_value used in my operation and need to run multiple selects. 
I tried this way but not succeceeded -

```
Insert into ABC (a,b,c) (select some_operation(d, <ext_value>) as a, e as b, f as c), (select some_operation(d, <ext_value>) as a, e as b, f as c);
```

I am expecting in the end if there is 2 select the ABC table will have double the no of rows in MDB, two rows each for each row in MDB.

How to do this operation in a single Mysql roundtrip or else should I have to make N queries to run the first query N times?

And If it is possible, would be great if some one explain How to implement the multiple selects insert in a single query from Magento.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html - no idea about magento though

Comment: In case the above link breaks `UNION`  or perhaps `Union all` depending on the data set is the keyword we think you're looking for to avoid roundtrips.

Comment: Yes I am looking to avoid rountrips. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `UNION` subquery that returns all the `ext_value` values, and join this with your table to get all the combinations.

```
INSERT INTO ABC (a, b, c)
SELECT some_operation(d, ext_value) AS a, e AS b, f AS c
FROM MDB_data
CROSS JOIN (SELECT <ext_value1> AS ext_value
            UNION
            SELECT <ext_value2> AS ext_value) AS x
```

I don't know Magento, so I don't know how to translate it to that format.